# Apache error "AliasMatch not allowed here"

Tags: apache, .htaccess, runtime-error

I get this error if I add this line in the .htaccess file:

```
AliasMatch ^/image/(.*)$ /ftp/pub/image/$1
```

And

```
Alias /image/ /ftp/pub/image/
```

produces same type of error

Why? :(

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Well error says all.

[As per official Apache docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#aliasmatch) `AliasMatch` and `Alias` are not allowed in `.htaccess`

You need to put them on Apache config.